# Attach SQL Server mdb file at runtime

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

I want to attach SQL Server 2005 database at runtime.

Can this be achieved without using local instance of SQL Server i.e. even without SQL Server Express?

Currently I'am using  following connection string is there any other workaround.

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|mydbfile.mdf; Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

Thanks,
Lalit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the 'runtime attach' is an Express only feature, see [SQL Server 2005 Express Edition User Instances.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264564%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

On a non-express SQL instance you you ask your DBA to attach the database properly. He knows how to do it, via: [sp_attach_db](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179877.aspx). Attaching a database has many implications on security, storage allocation, I/O patterns etc and applications should not attach databases themselves. Use an Express edition if you want the 'runtime attach' like behavior.